# Converting int to binary, using an array of char to represent it

Tags: c

Working on a homework assignment for class, part of the assignment has us converting from base ten to binary, and representing the binary number as an array of type char. For some reason it's not computing the right most bit. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
xtractmsg(int a)
{
   int rem,i,b,j,quotient;
   char binaryNumber[16];



   for(i = 0; i <= 16; i++){

        if(a == 0)
           binaryNumber[i]='0';
        else{

           rem = a % 2;

           if(rem == 0)
                   binaryNumber[i]='1';
           else
                  binaryNumber[i]='0';
          a=a/2;
        }


   }

    for(j=15; j>=0;j--)
        printf("%c,%d",binaryNumber[j]);


}
```

input is ten, output is 0000000000000101.

Comment: compile with maximal warnings turned on, that should tell you something about your `printf` call.

Comment: The error is very small. You've got most of it right.

Comment: yeah I deleted the extra %d, it was originally there to help me debug something else. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will not give you direct answer, because it is homework, I will point where to search for. Take a close look at what you do after you get a remainder. Try to print it right where you get it and analyze what you see.

Unrelated but also wrong `for(i = 0; i <= 16; i++)`, will eventually write to 17th element, which is nonexistent.

Comment: ah, I had my assignments reversed. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AdamTopi actually you shot your own foot, this condition `if(a == 0)` is completely unnecessary, `0 % 0 == 0`, so if it was not there you would notice that everything is just inverted. Try to write minimal but sufficient code, more code you have, more likely you have a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Two things here need addressing.

The loop condition is wrong by one-:

```
for(i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
```

The logic needs reversing-:

```
if(rem == 0)
    binaryNumber[i]='0';
else
    binaryNumber[i]='1';
```